# How to get value from Object

Tags: java, object, return-value

I need to know how I can get values from an Object.
For example:

```
public ConfirmDialog(String quest) {
    int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            quest,
            "Confirmation", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

When I return this object i didn't get the Integer. Can somebody give me an explanation? Google didn't help me..

```
Object b = new ConfirmDialog("Question?");
        System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: What do you mean you didn't get the Integer? Do you mean that `a` was not printed when u used `System.out.println(b);` ?

Comment: yes, this is my output: ConfimDialog@afe1bc5

Comment: There's no return statement. You make `a` but do nothing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print an `Object` and not the `int a`. When you pass an object at `System.out.println()` you are calling by default the `.toString()` method which attempts the give a textual representation of your object. What you get back is the `Object-Type` `@` `HexValue of the object hashcode` hense the `ConfimDialog@afe1bc5`

Now that you know that you need to call for the `int` and why you get this thing printed, there is a second problem. You create and initialize the variable `int a` inside your constructor, which means that you can't use it anywhere else. What you have to do is create it outside and initialize it every time you call that constructor, like this:

```
int a;
public ConfirmDialog(String quest) {
    int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            quest,
            "Confirmation", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Now you can print it using: `System.out.println(new ConfirmDialog("Question?").a);`

**NOTE THAT:** If you instantiate `ConfirmDialog()` like this:

`Object b = new ConfirmDialog("Question?");`

then you need to cast `b` to `ConfirmDialog` in order to access `a`, like this:

`System.out.println(((ConfirmDialog)b).get());`

Alternatively you can do it like this:

`ConfirmDialog b = new ConfirmDialog("Question?");` and just call `System.out.println(b.a);`

Generally though you should have private access to your variable and use getter methods. For example:

```
private int a;
public ConfirmDialog(String quest) {
    int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            quest,
            "Confirmation", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}

public int getA(){
    return a;
}
```

Now if you want to access `a` you can do: 
`System.out.println(new ConfirmDialog("Question?").getA());`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a local variable inside a constructor. Constructors are for creating objects and they donot have a return type. Try the below code:-

```
int a;
public ConfirmDialog(String quest) {
    a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            quest,
            "Confirmation", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}

public int get() {
   return a;
}

Object b = new ConfirmDialog("Question?");
System.out.println(((ConfirmDialog)b).get());
```

Comment: Because `b` is of type `Object`, `get` is inaccessible. `b` needs to be declared as type `ConfirmDialog` for `get` to become accessible - otherwise `b.get` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int a;

public ConfirmDialog(String quest) {
    a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            quest,
            "Confirmation", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

}
```

then:

```
ConfirmDialog b = new ConfirmDialog("Question?");
System.out.println(b.a);
```

[More information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

P.s. only for demo.. cause... code is creepy.. :)

Comment: Because `b` is of type `Object`, `a` is inaccessible. `b` needs to be declared as type `ConfirmDialog` for `a` to become accessible - otherwise `b.a` will fail.